# C program read text line by line with arithmetic operations per line

Tags: c, math, text, line, operation

I'm trying to make a program which will read arithmetic operations from text file as argument and output those results per line to another text file.

My input text file looks like this

```
    2+2
    3*4
    5-5
    8/2
```

This is a code that I have for now.

```c
    int main (int argc, char **argv) {
       char const* const fileName = argv[1];
        FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
        int bufferLength = 256;
        char buffer[bufferLength];
    
    while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, file)) {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    
    fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
```

Any of my line from the text file is in format `NUMBERarithmeticNUMBER` which is similar if I will do:

```c
int sum
sum = number1 + number2; // or any other operation
```

so I want to read every line as int variable in printf and output that to another text file. Problem for me is with printf - %d always output random numbers instead calculated operations.

I only noticed that bufferLength affects on randomness. It maybe can be connected with fileName too.
How to calculate arithmetic operations normally?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The output you get is just the text 2+2. Compiler doesn't know those are arithmetic unless you extract the information. You need to parse them and do the operation.

Comment: *so I want to read every line as int variable*. You can't. That doesn't make sense. Printing as `%d` doesn't magically evaluate the expression for you. You need to write code to extract and parse each part of the expression and then evaluate that expression.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) or `fscanf()` for a method to parse each line into variables for the operands and operator, e.g. `sscanf(buffer, "%d %c %d", &left, &op, &right)`. Then it's trivial to perform the calculations.

```
if (op == '+') result = left + right;
else if (op == '-') result = left - right;
// etc.
```

Or use a switch statement if you prefer that to an if/else ladder.